# Higher z-index box, doesn't overlap lower z-index one

Tags: css

Why is box2 not overlapping the box1 below it, when it has a higher z-index than box1?

```css
    .box1 {
      height: 30px;
      width: auto;
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
    .box2 {
      position: absolute;
      height: 20px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
<div class='box1'>
  Just a box
  <div class='box2'>Should overlap</div>
</div>

<div class='box1'>
  Why is this not partially hidden?
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k7m4y42L/
And another one, which resembles my HTML structure: http://jsfiddle.net/1nv8fd93/

Comment: Because it's nested inside a box that is one the same lvl.

Comment: Is it acceptable if You put `top:0` in `box2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are giving `box2` a z-index that's higher than the `z-index` of `box1`, but since you put it INSIDE a `box1`, the `z-index` gets reset in some way.

This means that everything that you give a z-index of <2 INSIDE a `box1` gets hidden under `box2`.

This problem can be solved in two ways: Pure CSS or with jQuery.

**CSS**

In CSS, it's easy: just change the `z-index` of `box1` on hover, like so:

```
.box1:hover {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

This will make the current `box1` you are hovering over have a higher `z-index` than the other `box1`s on the page. I have added a small `hover`-effect on `box2` as well, to get a bit more the end-product you want.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7m4y42L/3/)

**jQuery**

In jQuery it's a bit more complicated than necessary, but the result is the same as above (I'd go for the CSS solution). The piece of code below does the following:

> When the mouse hovers on `.box1`, it adds a `z-index: 3` to that specific `box1`, but ONLY if it contains a div with the class `box2`.

**jQuery**

```
$('.box1').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).has(".box2").css('z-index', 3);
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7m4y42L/4/).

In a way, the above is just a very complicate `:hover`-effect. It's only AFTER making this solution that I thought about adding a `:hover` on `box1` and adapting the `z-index`. But since it might be useful for some (probable none), I've left it in the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour with using only two classes?

Comment: Well, you'd want the whole of `box1` to overlap `box3` (from my example) so yes. Just give `box3` a lower `z-index` than `box1`. `box2` is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: Well, in my use case that won't do:| What I am trying to achieve, is showing a list of icons(box1's), and when the user hovers over one of the icon, a message appears (box2), that overlaps the icon below it:|

Comment: The thing is that HTML is 'read' from top to bottom. Since your first `box1` comes before the 2nd, it automatically gets behind the 2nd one. I'm going to play around with this, but as it looks like now, it can only be done with adding +1 to each following box, or with jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1nv8fd93/ Here's a more advanced fiddle, which resembles a lot more my current HTML structure

Comment: Check out the piece of text under **UPDATED ANSWER**

Comment: Damn, edited your answer, sorry, wanted to edit my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83540/discussion-between-adam-baranyai-and-rvervuurt).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the rule `top` because absolute "box2" is relative to "box1"

**CSS**

```
.box1 {
    height:30px;
    width: auto;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}

.box2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:2;
    top:0px; /* Set this rule */
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/k7m4y42L/1/)**

Comment: Yes, but what I want to achieve, is that box2 inside box1, should overlap EVERY box1, even the one that is below it. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your case is to use jquery to make these tooltips, rather than try to do it in css. Theres a simple demo of [Simple Tooltip with jQuery](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/jquery/simple-tooltip/) or better still, use something like [qTip](http://qtip2.com/demos) which makes prettier versions.